# Beacon scanner does not scan one beacon signal for more than 10 seconds

Tags: android, beacon, altbeacon, ibeacon-android

Hello I am poor at English.
I use Android Beacon Library

> implementation 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.15.2'

My Android application gradle imformation

> compileSdkVersion 28
>
> minSdkVersion 21
>
> targetSdkVersion 28

My Beacon manager information

> beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
>
> beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(1100L);
>
> beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1100L);
>
> beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(0);
>
> beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(0);
>
> beaconManager.enableForegroundServiceScanning(notificationcompatBuilder_Scannging.build(),456);
>
> beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false);
>
> BeaconManager.setDebug(true);
>
> regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, myBeaconRegion);

### Error

I want to develop all day beacon scanner application.

So I use regionBootstrap to scan in background.

It looked like it was working.

However time passed and Exit Event suddenly occurred and Enter Event occurred shortly after.

I think scan does not work for a few seconds and I have conducted a test on this.

#### Error Test 1

- one smartphone , two beacons
- [Error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFAce.png)
- One beacon signal is not detected for more than 10 seconds while another beacon signal is detected.
- So I think scan work well and it is a problem of beacon.

#### Error Test 2

- two smartphone , two beacons
- smartphone 1
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4RRn.png)
- smartphone 2
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZc27.png)
- In smartphone 1 Logcat, Also One beacon signal is not detected for more than 10 seconds while another beacon signal is detected.
- In smartphone 2 Logcat, Unscanned beacon is being scanned at the same time.
- So beacon does not problem and I can't find reason.

#### Error Test 3

- Added test
- two smart phone
- My beacon transmit the signal about once every three seconds.
- In smart phone 1, download the other beacon application which has beacon signal transmit and transmit at 1Hz.
- In smart phone 2, by using my application, watch the signal.
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEENV.png)
- The beacon signal of smart phone 1 increase markedly, but the same problem arose.

Does anyone know about this matter?
I want a help...
Please

Comment: I do not understand this statement: "In smartphone 2 Logcat, Unscanned beacon is being scanned at the same time."

Comment: Sorry... 

In logcat of smartphone 2, the beacon signal that wasn't scanned in smart phone 1 was scanned in same time (32sec~43sec)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the beacons you are using to test are not transmitting frequently enough.  Manufacturers often reduce the transmission rate to save battery.  When the transmission rate gets below 1Hz, this can cause problems, because not 100% of beacon packets transmitted are received by any phone.   Radio noise often causes packets to be missed.  If one device misses a few packets in a row (it happens sometimes) it causes a region exit event.

The solution is to increase the frequency at which the beacons transmit.  With some manufacturers this is configurable.  With others, it is not.  If it is not configurable, you may need to buy different beacons

You can test if this is the problem by using an Android beacon simulator app on one of the devices.  Try my [BeaconScope app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.davidgyoungtech.beaconscanner&hl=en_US), which will advertise at 10Hz by default.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My beacon transmit the signal about once every three seconds. And I downloaded your app and did test by 1 Hz beacon signal. But there was a problem as well. There was no signal between 10:16:34.808 ~ 10:16:47.215. And because of the battery of beacon, I can't raise the Hz over 1 Hz. Can you give me any other advice? Please.. help me....

Answer (score 0):

This library return result only when a specific event is triggered, not for all beacon scanned.. if you need this I suggest you to use the standart android standard beacon library, if you want to know more about this and how to implements comment this post and I'll edit it with the implementation

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My beacon transmit the signal about once every three seconds and if there are no signal during ten seconds, the exit event is triggered. But the debug mode of this library give me log of all beacon signal  like 

"beacon detected : id1: 2f234454-cf6d-4a0f-adf2-f4911ba9ffa6 id2: 1 id3: 1"
"beacon detected : id1: c01a269d-d9b8-3b36-a2b2-cf99e719f573 id2: 62497 id3: 54769". But I want to know about library you said. Please help me...

Comment: Ok wait and I help you